# How to edit contact notes

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWS Java API with Exchange Online (Office 365) and I would like to edit contact notes.

The problem I encounter is that there is no setter for a contact notes in this API. The contract is to bind a contact from its unique ID, set its properties then update it. However, There is no `setNotes()` on a contact. (The managed API does not provide setter either).

Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to use `getBody()` and `setBody()` methods.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, I am using ews-java-api-2.0.jar for service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);            
service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")); for exchange 2013 it give me error 'undefiend variable - Exchange2013'